# Converge or diverge? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {(\ln n)^a}{n^b}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Converge or diverge? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {(\ln n)^a}{n^b}$, $a > 0, b > 1$.

How do you approach this? Since every criteria I know gives $1$. What should I do?

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1.$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n)^{\frac 1n} = 1.$

I think this should converge for every $a,b$ with the restriction in hypothesis, right?

Comment: Hint: For large enough $n$ we have $(\ln n)^a<n^{(b-1)/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $b=1+2ac$ with $c\gt0$. Then show that

$${(\ln n)^a/n^{1+2ac}\over1/n^{1+ac}}=\left(\ln n\over n^c\right)^a\to0$$

**Remarks** (added later):  What we're really after is an inequality of the form

$${(\ln n)^a\over n^b}\le{B\over n^{1+p}}$$

for some $p\gt0$, in which case the convergence of $\sum{1\over n^{1+p}}$ guarantees the convergence of $\sum{(\ln n)^a\over n^b}$. So to be explicit, if we write $b=1+2ac$ and $p=ac$ (with $c={b-1\over2a}\gt0$), then we have

$${(\ln n)^a/n^b\over1/n^{1+p}}={(\ln n)^a/n^{1+2ac}\over1/n^{1+ac}}=\left(\ln n\over n^c\right)^a=\left(\ln n^c\over cn^c\right)^a\le\left(1\over ce \right)^a$$

where we use the fact that $f(x)={\ln x\over x}$ attains its maximum at $x=e$, where $f(e)={1\over e}$.  It follows that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(\ln n)^a\over n^b}\le\left(1\over ce \right)^a\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^{1+ac}}\lt\infty$$

where $c={b-1\over2a}$.  Writing it without the $c$, it's

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(\ln n)^a\over n^b}\le\left(2a\over (b-1)e \right)^a\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^{1+(b-1)/2}}\lt\infty$$

Comment: Woah, woah, slow down, why did you wrote it like that? to get the same power? and also why you need the $c$? Why the $2$? and what is the intuition behind that?

Comment: And why it is enough to show that it tends to $0$?

Comment: I wrote it that way just to make things look nice.  It's actually enough to show that the ratio is ultimately bounded, at which point ${(\ln n)^a\over n^{1+2ac}}\lt{B\over n^{1+ac}}$ shows that given series is bounded by a convergent series.

Comment: I don't think that's enough for me, can you be more explicit?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Apply the integral test, that is, consider the convergence of $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\log^a x \,dx}{x^b} = \int_0^{\infty} u^a e^{(1 - b) u} du .$$

Comment: is that looking the same as Gamma Function?

Comment: It can be transformed into an expression involving the Gamma function, yes.

Comment: (...but one doesn't need to know that to check convergence.)

Answer (score 0):

By [**Cauchy condensation test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) the condensed series is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {2^n(\ln 2^n)^a}{2^{bn}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {n^a\ln^a 2}{2^{n(b-1)}}$$

which converges for $b>1$.